# Mail Alert when threshold of 10000 pendingcmds are breached

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication, database-mail

I currently have the below running to monitor replication and send a mail when the threshold of 10000 pendingcmds are breached, however the alert mail is generated every 5 minutes regardless of the threshold. I need assistance to re-code the threshold part as this is not delivering the expected results.

```
        DECLARE @RESULT nvarchar(100)
        DECLARE @cmd varchar(100)

        SET @RESULT = ('SELECT pendingcmdcount FROM #pendingcmds') 
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @RESULT
        PRINT @RESULT
        IF @RESULT > '10000'
```

Code used to generate alert

```
        USE [TestDB]

        create table #pendingcmds
        (pendingcmdcount int,
        estimatedprocesstime int)

        Insert INTO #pendingcmds (pendingcmdcount, estimatedprocesstime)
        select * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 
        'Server=Server\Instance;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
        'set fmtonly off; 
        exec distribution..sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds 
        @publisher=''Server\Instance'', 
        @publisher_db=''testproduction'', 
        @publication=''Summary_Inventory_TestProduction'', 
        @subscriber=''Server'', 
        @subscriber_db=''TestReplAzure'', 
        @subscription_type=0')

        SELECT * FROM #pendingcmds

        --DECLARE @RESULT nvarchar(100)
        ----DECLARE @cmd varchar(100)
        --
        --SET @RESULT = ('SELECT pendingcmdcount FROM #pendingcmds') 
        --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @RESULT
        --PRINT @RESULT
        --IF @RESULT > '10000'
        --
        --BEGIN

         /*************************************************************/  
         /****************** HTML Preparation *************************/  
         /*************************************************************/

        DECLARE @HTML  VARCHAR(MAX),
                @table VARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @HTML = --HTML layout--
                        '<html><head>' +
                        '<H1 style="color: #000000">Publisher to Subscriber has exceeded threshold</H1>' +
                        '<style>' +
                        'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
                        '</style>' +
                        '</head>' +
                        '<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
                        '<tr bgcolor=#FF0000>'+  
                        '<td align=center>Pending CMD Count</b></td>' + 
                        '<td align=center>Estimated Process Time</b></td></tr>';  

        SELECT @table = CONVERT(nvarchar(max) ,
            (SELECT
             td = CAST(pendingcmdcount as varchar(30)), '',
             td = CAST(estimatedprocesstime as varchar(30)), '' 
             FROM #pendingcmds
             FOR XML PATH(N'tr'), TYPE));

        SET @HTML = @HTML + @table + CHAR(10) + 
                     N'</table></body></html>';

        SET @HTML = @HTML + '<TR></TR><B>End of Report</B></TABLE></BODY></HTML>';

        PRINT @HTML

        Declare @MailSubject varchar(100)
        SET @MailSubject = 'Alert - Publisher to Subscriber has exceeded threshold!!! - ' + DATENAME(weekday, getdate())

        IF LEN(@HTML) > 10 

            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @recipients = 'tester@test.com',
            @body_format =  'HTML',
            @body= @HTML,
            @subject = @MailSubject,
            @profile_name = 'MailRelay'

        DROP TABLE #pendingcmds
        --END

        --ELSE 
        --DROP TABLE #pendingcmds
        --
        --END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following suggestions are not fully tested.

Immediately after

```
Insert INTO #pendingcmds (pendingcmdcount, estimatedprocesstime)
select * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 
'Server=Server\Instance;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
'set fmtonly off; 
exec distribution..sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds 
@publisher=''Server\Instance'', 
@publisher_db=''testproduction'', 
@publication=''Summary_Inventory_TestProduction'', 
@subscriber=''Server'', 
@subscriber_db=''TestReplAzure'', 
@subscription_type=0')
```

I would delete any rows where your threshold was not met.

```
DELETE FROM #pendingcmds WHERE pendingcmdcount <= 10000
```

Then, I would change your test for whether to send the email or not

**From**

```
IF LEN(@HTML) > 10 

            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @recipients = 'tester@test.com',
            @body_format =  'HTML',
            @body= @HTML,
            @subject = @MailSubject,
            @profile_name = 'MailRelay'
```

**TO:**

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #pendingcmds) > 0 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'tester@test.com',
    @body_format =  'HTML',
    @body= @HTML,
    @subject = @MailSubject,
    @profile_name = 'MailRelay'
```